# Shell script to copy a text file from windows machine to linux based device

Tags: linux, shell, cygwin, file-transfer

A linux based navigation device is connected with my windows machine. I want to copy a text file to root of device using shell script from windows machine(through cygwin or putty). please help.

---

Acctually it is an navigation device connected with windows machine, some shell scripts are running on device an loggings are saved to the windows machine through putty. i want to transfer that log text to device through shell script.

Comment: Have you already tried using the windows explorer?

Comment: Is the Linux device mounted on the Windows one? Can it be mounted? What kind of device is it? We can't answer your question.